# system environment variable (VERCEL_URL) doesn't work

Tags: next.js, vercel

I want to add a condition one of my URLs in vercel. I'm using Next.js and my code is below

index.tsx

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [textEnv, setTextEnv] = useState<string>()
  const [textUrl, setTextUrl] = useState<string>()

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV == "development"){
      setTextEnv("this is from development")
    }else if(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV == "production"){
      setTextEnv("this is from production")
    }else if(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV == "preview"){
      setTextEnv("this is from preview")
    }else{
      setTextEnv("nothing else")
    }
    if(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL === "vercel-env-test-seven.vercel.app"){
      setTextUrl("this the url what I look for")
    }else{
      setTextUrl("other urls")
    }
  },[])
  return (
    <div>
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <Text>Type of Environment</Text>
        <Text>{textEnv}</Text>
        <Text>Name of the URL: </Text>
        <Text>{textUrl}</Text>
      </Box>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The result webpage: vercel-env-test-seven.vercel.app

I checked my project settings. Automatically expose System Environment Variables is ticked.
I tried also only VERCEL_URL but it doesn't work.
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV works, but VERCEL_URL doesn't work.
Can you help me where the problem is?

Comment: You have to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to expose environment variables to the browser.

Comment: @juliomalves I'm already using NEXT_PUBLIC_. You can see this in the code block in my post.

Comment: You said: _"NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV works, but VERCEL_URL doesn't work."_ - According to you it works with the prefix, so what's the issue?

Comment: @juliomalves The issue is that if NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL works, it should return string "this the url ..." when I am in the url : "vercel-env-test-seven.vercel.app". But it returns string " others urls" also in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to add the "NEXT_PUBLIC_" prefix **when defining an environment variable**, in order for it to be available in the browser. The system environment variables are pre-defined, which means that they are not available in the browser. Not sure why none of the documentation mentions this.

A workaround is to create a `.env.local` file with the following content:

> NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV="development"